# What is the difference between Coupled Cluster SD and SD(T)?

Tags: computational-chemistry

Can you explain the difference between these two computational methods ?

Answer (score 7):

In short, (T) means a perturbative (non-iterative) correction to a CCSD calculation. From a [talk demonstrating the derivation of the CCSD(T)](http://www.ipc.kit.edu/theochem/download/Kapitel3.pdf) method:

> The CCSD(T) method consists of a perturbative
> (noniterative) correction to the CCSD energy.
>
> • Utilizing the expressions from perturbation theory,
> approximate second order triples amplitudes *$\hat{T}^{(2)}_3$ are
> generated from the CCSD $\hat{T}_2$ amplitudes (rather than from
> first order amplitudes).
>
> • The second order corrected wave function is then used to
> compute the fourth and fifth order energy corrections, which
> are added to the CCSD energy.

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupled_cluster) has a decent page about CC in general. A very good [review](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/9780470125915.ch2)<sup>[1]</sup> by T. Daniel Crawford and Henry F. Schaefer III is available online. There is a section discussing the (T) correction specifically.
[*Rev. Comput. Chem.* **2007,** 33–136](https://doi.org/10.1002/9780470125915.ch2)

#### References:

1. Crawford, T. D.; Schaefer, H. F. An Introduction to Coupled Cluster Theory for Computational Chemists. *Rev. Comput. Chem.* **2007,** 33–136. [DOI: 10.1002/9780470125915.ch2](https://doi.org/10.1002/9780470125915.ch2).

Comment: Yann: Your links to UGA are broken now.

Answer (score 3):

There are many ways to answer this, but CCSD is only complete through third-order in many-body perturbation theoretic terms, while CCSD(T) is complete through fourth-order.  It was the desire to have a fourth-order complete method that led Bartlett and coworkers to develop CCSD[T].  The CCSD(T) method includes a fifth-order term (at least in the RHF case), which was later [shown](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0009261497011445) to be fourth-order in the ROHF case by Stanton, which helps to explain why the inclusion of that term has such an impact on the accuracy of CCSD(T) relative to CCSD[T].

The [CFOUR Bibliography page](http://www.cfour.de) has a list of most (all?) the seminal papers on coupled-cluster theory, which might be of interest.